# Sed capitalize first letter of word in key-value pair

Tags: bash, sed, find

I'm currently working on my karaoke files and i see a lot of Non capitalized words.

The `.txt` files are structured as a key-value pair and i was wondering how to capitalize the first letter of every value word.

Example `txt`:

```
#TITLE:fire and Water
#ARTIST:Some band
#CREATOR:yunho
#LANGUAGE:Korean
#EDITION:UAS
#MP3:2NE1 - Fire.mp3
#COVER:2NE1 - Fire.jpg
#VIDEO:2NE1 - Fire.avi
#VIDEOGAP:11.6
#BPM:595
#GAP:3860
F -4 4 16  I
F 2 4 16  go
F 8 6 16  by
F 16 4 16  the
F 22 6 16  name
F 30 4 16  of
F 36 10 16  C
F 46 10 16 L
F 58 6 16  of
F 66 5 16  2
F 71 3 16 N
F 74 4 16 E
F 78 18 16 1
```

I'd like to capitalize the words after the keys `TITLE`, `ARTISTS`, `LANGUAGE` and `EDITION`

so for the example `txt`:

```
#TITLE:**F**ire **A**nd **W**ater
#ARTIST:**S**ome **B**and
#CREATOR:yunho
#LANGUAGE:**K**orean
#EDITION:**U**AS
#MP3:2NE1 - Fire.mp3
#COVER:2NE1 - Fire.jpg
#VIDEO:2NE1 - Fire.avi
#VIDEOGAP:11.6
#BPM:595
#GAP:3860
F -4 4 16  I
F 2 4 16  go
F 8 6 16  by
F 16 4 16  the
F 22 6 16  name
F 30 4 16  of
F 36 10 16  C
F 46 10 16 L
F 58 6 16  of
F 66 5 16  2
F 71 3 16 N
F 74 4 16 E
F 78 18 16 1
```

Another thing is that i have loads of these txt's files all in designated directories. I want to run the program from the parent recursive for all *.txt files

Example directories:

```
Library/Some Band/Some Band - Some Song/some txt file.txt
Library/Some Band2/Some Band2 - Some Song/sometxtfile.txt
Library/Some Band3/Some Band3 - Some Song/some3333 txt file.txt
```

I've tried to do so with `find . -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i command {} +`
but i got stuck on the search and replace with sed... anyone care to help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `gnu-sed` command to uppercase starting letter for matching lines:

```
sed -E '/^#(TITLE|ARTIST|LANGUAGE|EDITION):/s/\b([a-z])/\u\1/g' file

#TITLE:Fire And Water
#ARTIST:Some Band
#CREATOR:yunho
#LANGUAGE:Korean
#EDITION:UAS
#MP3:2NE1 - Fire.mp3
#COVER:2NE1 - Fire.jpg
#VIDEO:2NE1 - Fire.avi
#VIDEOGAP:11.6
#BPM:595
#GAP:3860
F -4 4 16  I
F 2 4 16  go
F 8 6 16  by
F 16 4 16  the
F 22 6 16  name
F 30 4 16  of
F 36 10 16  C
F 46 10 16 L
F 58 6 16  of
F 66 5 16  2
F 71 3 16 N
F 74 4 16 E
F 78 18 16
```

For `find + sed` command use:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec \
sed -E -i '/^#(TITLE|ARTIST|LANGUAGE|EDITION):/s/\b([a-z])/\u\1/g' {} +
```

Comment: hmmm am i doing something wrong?: `sed: -e expression #1, char 54: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS` ?

Comment: I'm coming back to this question. Sometimes within the title there is a `'` for example in `Don't Stop Me Now` by Queen. Right now it also capitalizes the `t` from `Don't` too. Resulting in: `Don'T Stop Me Now`

Comment: This makes it worse; `I Don't want To miss A Thing` results into `I Don't Want To MisS‌​ A Thing` Note the characters while trying to delete the `S` Of Miss ( i had to press backspace thrice)

Comment: oh ok try: `sed -E '/^#(TITLE|ARTIST|LANGUAGE|EDITION):/s/([: ])([a-z])/\1\u\2/g' file`

Comment: For the damage what is done already. Is there anyway to rename the letter behind a `'` to lowercase?

Comment: if i'm using this on `#TITLE:I'M With You` it does nothing, i tried adding the the conditional tags `find . -name '*.txt' -exec sed -E -i "/^#(TITLE|ARTIST|LANGUAGE|EDITION):/s/'([A-Z])/'\1/g" {} +` Since it only has to apply to those (as those have been changed)

Comment: sorry, try this: `sed -E "s/'([A-Z])/'\l\1/g" file`